# FCM display gray icon in Notification Bar and provides empty getData() getExtras()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm integrating FCM for managing the notifications for an iOS and Android mobile application. For iOS everything works well: Background/Foreground Server/Console messages.

For Android I was impossible to make it work smooth.

**Using the console or sending server notifications**

1 - When I sent a notification and the app is in background, the notification center always display a grey square instead of the defined icon in the Manifest, or in the payload. The icon in the status bar, before unfold the notification center is the right one.

I tried specifying the global round @drawable/resource_name or just resource_name with the same result

2 - When the app is in foreground everything works well, but when the app is in background the onMessageReceived() is never triggered, the SO display a notification automatically in the notification center, transparent for the app, and if/when the user clicks the notification in the notification center the Activity with the DEFAULT is raised but both getIntent().getData() and getIntent().getExtra() have null, and I'm passing parameters proceed successfully if the app is in Foreground.

**Manifest.xml**

```
     <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="appName"
                android:scheme="appName" />
            <data
                android:host="subdomain.domain.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

...

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@android:color/black" />

        <!-- Used for FireBase Messaging and Analytics -->
        <service
            android:name=".services.MessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".services.TokenService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Any advice?

Comment: I upgraded the project to the 10.2.1, so the gradle is the following:            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
And still the same problem. It seems for raise the onReceivedMessage you must include all the params in data, and not in the notification payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1**

There was a problem with the image resource itself, following the OneSignal documentation I created a new one working.

Was special useful the following online [tool](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_onesignal_default)

**Problem 2**

The web console from FCM includes always a notification payload. It suppose that if you also include data payload when you click on the local notification the data payload is included as Extra (Bundle) in the new intent. But this is not happening.

Using the API and just including data payload everything works well, you must handle the location notification manually as expected.

Finally I decide to move to another approach (OneSignal) because the limitations of the FCM web console.